# How can I set the outline color for a barplot in Python?

Tags: python, charts, outline

I am creating a simple barplot:

```
ax = lasso_output_df2.plot(kind='bar', title ="Spain Coefficient Variables [alpha_10]", figsize=(15, 10), legend=False,  fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticklabels(lasso_output_df2.Features)
ax.set_axis_bgcolor('white')
```

What element do i need to include to specifiy an outline for the chart ?

I tried `edgecolor = 'black'` but this changed the outline of the bars, not the plot.

**My current plot.**
[image]

**And my desired out come.**
[image]